# Using Moq and IFlurlClientFactory and IFlurlClient

Tags: c#, moq, flurl

I have a question on how to test / mock out the IFlurlClientFactory and IFlurlClient.
I'm registering my service (as a singleton eventually via DI), which uses the IFlurlClientFactory in a following way:

```
public ImageRetrievalServiceClientV1(
    IFlurlClientFactory flurlClientFactory        
)
{
    _flurlClient = flurlClientFactory.Get(someUrl);       
}
```

A method is defined in the ImageRetrievalServiceClientV1 where I use the `_flurlClient` as instantiated above, as follows:

```
await _flurlClient.Request("some", "path", "segements")
                .WithOAuthBearerToken(token)
                .PostJsonAsync(someObject);
```

Question: Is there a nice way that can I mock out the `IFlurlClientFactory` and `IFlurlClient` using the Moq testing framework? Thanks in advance for the answers.

Regards, Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UPDATE]: I misunderstood the whole point of the HttpTest. Fortunately the [docs](https://flurl.dev/docs/testable-http/#arrange) are clarifying things which I apparently missed in the first instance... -_-'

What I just needed to do was to instantiate HttpTest in my unittest. For example if I want my sut to throw a `FlurlHttpException` I just need to tell the httpTest instance to respond with, for example, a server error:

```
using var httpTest = new HttpTest();
//httpTest.RespondWith("some response body");
httpTest.RespondWith("server error", 500);
```

Instantiate a new `PerBaseUrlFlurlClientFactory`:

```
var sut = new ImageRetrievalServiceClientV1(new PerBaseUrlFlurlClientFactory(),....);
```

Subsequent calls on the sut which trigger the calls are mocked out because of the setup of the `HttpTest`. This works like a charm!

Comment: Much easier than all the mocking. :) I'll just suggest adding a `using` to make sure things get cleaned up when the test exists.

Comment: Thanks @ToddMenier for your answer! I will add the suggested `using var` to my httptest instantiation to cleanup things after the tests have ran.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `Mock<IFlurlClientFactory>` which is configured to spit out a `Mock<IFlurlClient>`. If you hang on to the mocked client, you can then configure that as needed for the purpose of your tests.

```
//Set up a mocked factory to return a mocked client
var clientFactoryMock = new Mock<IFlurlClientFactory>();
var clientMock = new Mock<IFlurlClient>();

clientFactoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetClient(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(clientMock.Object);

//Set up the client. Assuming a fluent approach where IFlurlClient actions returns itself for chaining calls
clientMock.Setup(x => x.WithOAuthBearerToken(It.IsAny<string>()).Returns(clientMock.Object);
clientMock.Setup(x => x.PostJsonAsync(It.IsAny<JSONObjectType>()).Returns(...);
```

Comment: Nice! I was thinking about this solution also but I was a little bit in doubt because there is also a nice `HttpTest` class that Flurl provides.

Comment: You might find that using the built-in `HttpTest` bits is a more natural fit for the tests you want to write given support for it is baked in. I'd suggest trying to write tests for a couple of the more tricky scenarios you may have with both `Moq` and `HttpTest` and see which approach works best for you.

Comment: The `.WithOAuthBearerToken(...)` and `PostJsonAsync(...)` are extensions on the `IFlurlRequest` object. Moq cannot setup extension methods.

Comment: In that case, you are likely going to need to tweak your code to "hide" these extension methods in a way where you can isolate and replace the usage of those extension methods with mocked equivalents. The simplest way to do this may be with a wrapper/adapter around the relevant Flurl bits where you create a test-only equivalent that is simply a stub.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was just wondering if there is something already present in the Flurl libs or if someone out there who managed to do this. Lookse like I have to implement wrappers/adapters myself.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need multiple mock objects. For example, this should get you part way there. The key is to create the objects in reverse order since the first one is created by the second.

```
var clientMock = new Mock<IFlurlClient>();
clientMock.Setup(c => c.Request(
        It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())
    .Returns("<not sure what goes in here since I don't know much about Flurl>");

// You will need to figure out how to deal with WithOAuthBearerToken and 
// PostJsonAsync  but it's likely you need another mock.

var factoryMock = new Mock<IFlurlClientFactory>();
factoryMock.Setup(f => f.Get(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(clientMock.Object);
```